# Package gnuradio-core was not found

Tags: configure, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to run `configure`command for `gnuradio-802.15.4-demodulation` file downloaded from github.

It is showing these error.

> checking for gnuradio-core >= 2... Package gnuradio-core was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gnuradio-core.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'gnuradio-core' found
>
> configure: error: Library requirements (gnuradio-core >= 2) not met; consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix so pkg-config can find them.

i have already installed `gnuradio-companion` and its working well.

I do not much programming and kindly tell what is the problem in simple terms and what correction i should make?

Comment: I don't what you're referring to? Maybe gr-ieee802-15-4? That comes with instructions how to build, and as the whole GNU Radio ecosystem, these don't use autoconf, at all, but cmake.

Comment: Answered on https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2017-10/msg00108.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cite the answer I gave you on https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2017-10/msg00108.html

> Hi Rensi,
>
> ah, your Stackoverflow Question[1] could really use that link!
>
> That module was last touched 9 years ago; pretty certainly dead[0]. It
>   simply won't work with any GNU Radio you'll find these days. GNU
>   Radio, and its whole ecosystem, moved away from autoconf/automake a
>   couple of years ago. So, if something has to do with GNU Radio and
>   needs to be ./configure'd, then it's safe to say it won't work
>   anymore.
>
> Instead, look into Basti's gr-ieee802-15-4[2]. It's maintained, it
>   actually does the whole PHY stack, it's easy to build. Also, there's
>   based-upon / similar modules that do other 802.15.4 PHYs, as there's
>   more than the O-QPSK that your link uses; namely:
>
> ```
> O-QPSK PHY: [2]
> CSS PHY: [2]
> LECIM DSSS PHY: [3]
> PSSS PHY: In the making, watch [3]/[4] for new additions
> ```
>
> Best regards,
>
> Marcus
>
> [0] https://youtu.be/MH7KYmGnj40
>
> [1]
>   [Package gnuradio-core was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782512/package-gnuradio-core-was-not-found)
>
> [2] https://github.com/bastibl/gr-ieee802-15-4
>
> [3] https://github.com/kit-cel/gr-lpwan
>
> [4] https://github.com/kit-cel/